# Dictionary of dictionary of lists of dictionaries, map values to same key

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

```
{'page_1': [{'useless': '73636763'},
  {'good': 'info is good'},
  {'good': 'info is also good'},
  {'nice': 'info is nice'},
  {'nice': 'info is also nice '}],
'page_2': [{'useless': '87465432'},
  {'good': 'info is good on page 2'},
  {'good': 'info is also good on page 2'},
  {'nice': 'info is nice on page 2'},
  {'nice': 'info is also nice on page 2'}]}
```

How do I sort this dict to look like this:

```
{
    'page_1': [{'useless': '73636763'}, 
    {'good': ['info is good', 'info is also good']},
    {'nice': ['info is nice', 'info is also nice']}], 
    'page_2': [{'useless': '87465432'}, 
    {'good': ['info is good on page 2', 'info is also good on page 2']},
    {'nice': ['info is nice on page 2', 'info is also nice on page 2']}]
}
```

I have tried to use `defaultdict` for this purpose but I not able to find a way to keep the keys `page_1` and `page_2` as:

```
for item in mydict:
    for pair in mydict[item]:
        for key, value in pair.items():
            dict_from_collections[key].append(value)
```

`dict_from_collections` is an empty `defaultdict(list)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the dict of lists of singleton dicts into a dict of dicts first, and then convert the sub-dicts to lists of singleton dicts:

```
output = {}
for page, lst in mydict.items():
    for [(key, value)] in map(dict.items, lst):
        output.setdefault(page, {}).setdefault(key, []).append(value)
for page, mapping in output.items():
    output[page] = list(map(dict, zip(mapping.items())))
```

`output` becomes:

```
{'page_1': [{'useless': ['73636763']}, {'good': ['info is good', 'info is also good']}, {'nice': ['info is nice', 'info is also nice ']}], 'page_2': [{'useless': ['87465432']}, {'good': ['info is good on page 2', 'info is also good on page 2']}, {'nice': ['info is nice on page 2', 'info is also nice on page 2']}]}
```

Demo: https://replit.com/@blhsing/DeadlySkyblueBaitware

Comment: This turned out to be a bit more complicated than I anticipated. I couldn't have figured it out myself. Much thanks.